# how do I run multiple executables code at the same time using bash?

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to run multiple c code at the same time using bash but don't know how ?

This code works but it runs one code and then waits until it finishes running to run the next one.
I'd like to run them all at the same time.

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                  
MAXLEVEL=8
for Oh in '0.0005'
do

    for H in '0.1' '0.5' '1.' '1.5' '2.'
    do
        mkdir half$Oh$H
        cp half h.py RP.py `pwd`/half$Oh$H/
        cd half$Oh$H
        mpirun -np 4 ./half $Oh $H $MAXLEVEL
        cd ..
    done
done
```

Do you have any ideas ?
Thanks you.

Comment: start in background `mpirun -np 4 ./half $Oh $H $MAXLEVEL &`

Comment: `mpirun -np 4 ./half $Oh $H $MAXLEVEL &` and then `wait` after the last `done`

Comment: The language in which your programs are implemented has little, if anything, to do with it.

Comment: You run *executables* not C code. It really doesn't matter which compiled language was used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can detach the output of the bash shell by adding a `&` at the end of it, to be able to do another commmand in the meanwhile.

Example :

```
echo "hello, i will go to sleep" && sleep 5 && echo "I Finished sleeping !" & echo "Second command here !"
```

Will output:

```
$ Second command here !
$ hello, i will go to sleep
$ I Finished sleeping !
```

The two first lines can be inverted, it depends of the execution time of the commands.

Comment: I would mention `wait` too or else OP:s script may/will exit while the background processes are running which may kill them.

Comment: yes without a wait background processes are killed.  process_id=$!                     
 srun --mpi=pmi2 ./half $Oh $H $MAXLEVEL &     
 wait $process_id

Comment: @Suntory, I've just switched the answer to Community Wiki so you can improve it with your idea, since I'm not competent enough to do it. Hope it will help :)